# Javascript location.href crash on Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, internet-explorer-11, contact-form-7

Today, I noticed this issue in IE11.

A simple JavaScript redirect (made via `location.href = 'newhost...';`) causes the browser to crash.

Does anyone have any idea how can this be fixed?

If it helps this happened using ContactForm7 on wordpress using this method: http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Comment: Please provide a full re-produceable example in your post, pages behind links comes and goes...

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't always play nice with `location.href` or `window.location.href` in javascript. i.e. more so the `href` function...

Try using:

```
window.location.assign("newhost.."); // or
window.location = "newhost..";
```

> **window.location:**
> As described in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location).
> The Window.location read-only property returns a
>   `Location` object with information about the current location of the
>   document.
>
> Though `Window.location` is a read-only Location object, you can also
>   assign a `DOMString` to it. This means that you can work with
>   `document.location` as if it were a string in most cases:
>   `window.location = 'http://www.example.com'` is a synonym of
>   `window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this problem in a WordPress forums post here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirection-crashes-ie-11-perfect-for-all-others

KookRoss says:

> I found a solution to this, its an ugly one but it does get around the
>   issue for me.

```
on_sent_ok:
"$("#post-440").empty();window.location.replace('https://www.url.com.au/thank-you/');"
```

> Where post-440 is the ID of the div which surrounds the form. Put
>   simply your post led me to the belief that IE is somehow passing that
>   form again before doing the redirection, this uses jQuery to clear
>   that entire page of content (including the form) before doing the
>   redirection.
>
> Its a hack way to get around the IE issue but so far its working in
>   all browsers for me including IE11.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this error even using Assign in IE 11 when redirect from an event, you can use:

```
setTimeout(function ()
{
   window.location.assign("newhost...");
}, 100);
```

To get around the problem